# Hourly temperature reporting

Tags: python

Write a loop to print all elements in `hourly_temperature`. Separate elements with a `->` surrounded by spaces.

Sample output for the given program with input: `'90 92 94 95'`

```
90 -> 92 -> 94 -> 95
```

Note: `95` is followed by a space, then a newline.

Given:

```
user_input = input()
hourly_temperature = user_input.split()
```

Comment: I have tried this code                                                                                   
hourly_temperature = [90, 92, 94, 95]
ordered_temps = []
for temp in hourly_temperature:
    ordered_temps.append(temp)
    if not temp == hourly_temperature[-1]:
        ordered_temps.append(" -> ")
    else:
        ordered_temps.append(" ")
print("".join(map(str, ordered_temps)))

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please put all information/code in your post and not in the comments.

Comment: Sorry it wouldn't allow me to enter my code in my post

Comment: What errors do you get when you try?

Comment: What is your question? It likely didn't allow you to [edit] your question and add your code because it thinks your question is mostly code and that looks like a code-dump. You should ask a _specific_ question about the issue you run into, and include anything you learned from any [debugging](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) you did. Please take the [tour], and read [ask] and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648). Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: One liner: `' -> '.join(hourly_temperature)`

Answer (score 0):

From your description, what you are doing:

```
user_input[string] --> hourly_temperature [list] --> Sample output[string]
```

If that's the case, you can simply modify the string instead of splitting and joining it:

```
result = user_input.replace(" ", " -> ")+' \n
```